# Running model.save() method asynchronously?

Tags: python, django, asynchronous

I am wondering if it is possible to run a save method for a model that I've overwritten asynchronously? If so how would you implement it?

Comment: can you explain the point of this? does your save take a long time? or there is another issue?

Comment: @aliva the save takes around 5 minutes because it has to insert 50000 records. I am trying to have it run in the background so the user can do other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for web development you have to return a response quickly and using threads or multiprocessing won't help (user will reach timeout and your task will fail

the solution is writing a background task runner (using something like [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/))

when user sends a request you send a task call to celery and invoke the background task, the task will run in another process (creating those rows) and you can return a response to user saying your request is being processed.

Answer (score 0):

why not use multiprocessing

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

pool = Pool(processes=1)
result = pool.apply_async(model.save)
```

to spawn a new process to save your model. you can pass whatever parameters like a path using other arguments in `apply_async` aswell.